# Points within buffer with the same id

Tags: r, buffer, geopandas, pandas

I have a buffer layer and a point layer:

```
 buffer_gdf
     ID
0    1A
1    1B
2    1C
```

and

```
 point_gdf
      ID
0     1A
1     1A
2     1A
3     1A
4     1A
5     1B
6     1B
7     1B
8     1B
9     1B
10    1B
11    1B
12    1B
13    1B
14    1C    
15    1C
16    1C
17    1C    
18    1C
19    1C
20    1C    
21    1C
22    1C
```

Is there a way to count how many points with ID=1A are within buffer ID=1A, how many points ID=1B are within buffer ID=1B, how many points ID=1C are within buffer ID=1C, and so on... I have more than 20000 buffers and more than 300000 points.

I'm using pandas but I can also use R.

There are points ouside the buffers, I just need to count those within the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is first select the point with the same ID and then use the spatial join to see if they are inside the buffer. But we need a column to store the count:

```
buffer_gdf["pt_count"] = 0
for index, buffer_row in buffer_gdf.iterrows():
    temp_points = point_gdf.loc[point_gdf["ID"] == buffer_row["ID"],"ID"].copy()
    joined = gpd.sjoin(temp_points, buffer_row, op="intersect", how="right")
    buffer_gdf.loc[index, "pt_count"] = len(joined)
```

The count of points within each buffer is going to be recorded in `pt_count` column.